# TypeScript error for instance method invocation via instance[methodName]

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Consider a simple ES6 class:

```js
class myClass{
 constructor() {}
 method()   {}
 methodA() {}
 methodB() {}
 methodC() {}
 methodABC() {}
 // .. more
}
```

Some static method for `myClass` should call one of the instance methods but it's not known which one unless the context is right. but the `methodName` is always determined from other string values.

This is an oversimplification of the actual code, I don't expect it to be valid, but as close as possible to the problem itself:

```js
function getSome(person) {
 const instance = new someClass();
 const { interests, isCool } = person;
 const report = {};

 // many many likes
 const context = ['likesA', 'likesB', 'likesC', 'likesABC', /*...*/];

 // define a kinda default
 let methodName = '';

 interests.forEach(interest => {

  // a known pattern for about 4 cases
  if (interest.includes('A') && isCool) {
   methodName = interest.replace('alpha', 'omega'); // => 'methodA';
  }
  
  // another pattern for 4-5 cases
  // and so on

  // an error is thrown here, see below
  report[interest] = instance[methodName]();
 });

 return report;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```js
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type when accessing instance method 'myClass'.
// No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'myClass'
```

Questions:

- is there a way to write the ES6 code so that TypeScript is happy?
- is there a `tsconfig.json` setting I might need?
- is this a case of `// @ts-ignore`?

Comment: [It works for me.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEEPYFsCmBhcVoG8BQ1rIBcALOAEwEEAKASkwF9d8liyAhG+7B7AMwFcAdsAIBLOAOgBzZgGVESSkhBJkAggC5oggNYC4AdwHUsuYOIgFoIgRbBCk0ALzQBSfbHlpIEGgG5T5paEJKQAcmDITtBKKkhqVjYEdsBIcDzQMgBqAOIAosqqlgD80ADkwWTkpdCa5cwhrKX+uAD0LdB20QBOXXBdVjDEvYbQREhdSLgTBHxdEta29gDaFWERSAC6flxAA) Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The code works but TypeScript throws the error.

Comment: Typescript **doesn't** throw an error (check the playground link in my previous comment). The erroring setup you have is clearly different from the one you included in your post.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?  @Aplet123's example seems to work fine.  You can also try writing this as `const method = element instanceof SVGElement ? instance.methodA : instance.methodB`, and calling `return method();` as an alternative

Comment: TS 4.4.4. I need to be able to call the instance method via `instance[methodName]` because there are too many methods. That's the tip of the iceberg since `let methodName` is to be changed based on more than `element instanceof SVGElement` condition, in one case it's a string which could result from `let methodName = source.replace('X','')`.

Comment: @SethLutske `instance.methodName` is not valid code, perhaps it's a case of `// @ts-ignore`?

Comment: I never wrote `instance.methodName`...not sure where you're getting that from.  But considering we don't have a reproducible example, the initial bug you're asking about doesn't seem to be a bug at all.  Please post a reproducible example.  My suggestion was just that - a suggestion.  To me its just as verbose and awkward as your original code, but they both seem to work just fine.

Comment: [This TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEEPYFsCmBhcVoG8BQ1rIBcALOAEwEEAKASkwF9d8liyAhG+7B7AMwFcAdsAIBLOAOgBzZgGVESSkhBJkAggC5oggNYC4AdwHUsuYOIgFoIgRbBCk0ALzQBSfbHlpIEGgG5T5paEJKQAcmDITtBKKkhqVjYEdsBIcDzQMgBqAOIAosqqlgD80ADkwWTkpdCa5cwhrKX+AYnQPGDaSOHIMM4xhQm29mkZOfmx8SV1LBTVtXoCuQAeIhZxBE3YjNZDKQDa0yFVALp+24nJSAcVpI2n1P54O0n2ezfdSPfNTxevpfDBaySUpfc67K7tTofCCg3AAejh0Ds0QATii4CirDBiOjDNAiEgUUhcESCHwURJnpc3vUyB9QXQgA) shows that your tactic really works.  Typescript is smart enough to detect if the method exists in your class - I don't see a problem

Comment: Once you're using `let` (or typing `methodName` as `string`) TS can't  verify if it is valid member of `myClass`

Comment: OK let me rephrase the question. I feel more context is required.

Comment: Question edited. @AlekseyL. what would you suggest?

Comment: I guess `// @ts-ignore`. No way for typescript to know if generated at runtime strings are actually a method names. You could also disable `noImplicitAny` compiler option, but I wouldn't recommend this